# How to get constant term in AR Model with statsmodels and Python?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I'm trying to model my time series data using the AR model.

[image]

This is the code that I'm using.

```
# Compute AR-model (data is a python list of number)

model = AR(data)
result = model.fit()

plt.plot(data, 'b-', label='data')
plt.plot(range(result.k_ar, len(data)), result.fittedvalues, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

I've successfully get the p value using `result.k_ar`, parameter with `result.params`, epsilon term with `result.sigma2`. The problem is that I can't find a way to get the c (constant) term. Here is the code I write to compare the result.

```
# Plot

fit = []
for t in range(result.k_ar, len(data)):
    value = 0
    for i in range(1, result.k_ar+1):
        value += result.params[i-1] * data[t - i]
    fit.append(value)

plt.plot(data, 'b-', label='data')
plt.plot(range(result.k_ar, len(data)), fit, 'r-', label='fit')
plt.plot(range(result.k_ar, len(data)), result.fittedvalues, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

My result and the result from `result.fittedvalues` confirm my evident that there is some constant term added to the model. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constant is the zero-th element in params. E.g., params[0].

Your code should be

```
fit = []
for t in range(result.k_ar, len(data)):
    value = result.params[0]
    for i in range(2, result.k_ar + 2):
        value += result.params[i - 1] * data[t - i + 1]
    fit.append(value)
```

Or even easier, since we've made the lag matrix for you (this is what fittedvalues does)

```
np.dot(result.model.X, result.params)
```

As an aside, note that for AR this is actually the constant and not the mean. The mean is reported by the ARMA model, which is a bit more full-featured than the plain AR model. (It has a summary method that reports the constant. AR should too but doesn't.) The connection is

```
constant = mean(1 - arparams.sum())
```

Comment: According to the equation should I add the epsilon to the result (`fit.append(value + result.sigma2`)?

Comment: No, but you can use sigma2 to get estimates for forecast uncertainty. There's a PR to put this into AR but for now it's only available in ARMA/ARIMA.

Comment: I have tried using ARMA but still got some problems. Could you please help me looking at this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24331886/1241606